# One time call http request using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  function get (id, ignore) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('v1/info/' + id, {
      ignoreAuthModule: ignore
    })
      .success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
      })
      .error(function (reason) {
        deferred.reject(reason.message););
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

init();

function init(){
 users.get($routeParams.id)
    .then(function (data) {
        if(data.has_something === 1){
          $scope.hasSomething = true;
        }else{
          $scope.hasSomething = false;
        }

    });
}
```

I have a Service that get the information about user using promise and Fetching information from the service with init function
//if i call init function this should call two times one from function initialization and other i'm calling it from service
how can i stop two times calling api I mean it should call one time if already called

Comment: you can store user information in scope variable for later use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the explicit promise creation antipattern here, and your code could be much simpler. Here is how you can use memoization to avoid requesting the same user twice:

```
.factory('users', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var userPromises = {};

    function get (id, ignore) {
        if (!userPromises[id]) {
            userPromises[id] = $http.get('v1/info/' + id, {
                ignoreAuthModule: ignore
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                return data.data;
            })
            .catch(function (reason) {
                throw new Error(reason.message);
            });
        }

        return userPromises[id];
    }

    return {
        get: get
    };
});
```

Comment: @JLRishe how could this could updated once changes being done from api i.e if item updated from database and we do not reload it should call else reject the promise

Answer (score -1):

You can assign your `deferred.promise` to some variable and then return that variable, and before your http call just check whether that variable is already defined or not

```
function get (id, ignore) {
  if (angular.isUndefined(user)) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('v1/info/' + id, {
      ignoreAuthModule: ignore
    }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status == 200) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
      } else {
        deferred.reject(response.data);
      };

    user =  deferred.promise;
    return user;
   } else {
    return user;
   }
  }
```

This way your api will get called only once.

Comment: Good approach but... 1) You've implemented the deferred anti-pattern, 2) `success` and `error` are deprecated and removed in Angular 1.6, and 3) You're using an implied global variable `user`

Comment: Thanks @Phil for pointing that out. I just used code which is mentioned in question, updating my answer using then

Comment: This only ever allows retrieving one user. What if they need to query user with ID 9 and then the user with id 14? It'll return a promise for the same user both times.

Comment: Now you're using `response.status` incorrectly. In the success callback (first arg passed to `then`), the response will always reflect a successful status. If you want an error callback, use the second arg of `then` or use `catch`. Also, you're still implementing the deferred anti-pattern and you still have a global `user` variable

Comment: @user6606700 This answer is wrong, for the reason I stated above. Try using it to request two different users during the same session and you will see this.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for this. I agree your answer should be accepted one.

Comment: @nishantagrawal Thank you :)